# IIS 6, tool to copy all site host headers?

Tags: iis-6, hostheaders

I have a Server 2003 box with about 6 sites that each have about 15-20 host headers.

Is there a tool out there that will copy all the host header records and automatically move them to the new server so I don't have to manually enter each host header again in the new server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you save the configuration via the IIS Manager (right-click All Tasks -> Save Configuration to a file) this will export all the host header information along with everything else about the website. Then on the new server you can import this configuration to recreate the website.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the Web Deployment Tool, which can sync settings between IIS servers:
http://www.iis.net/downloads/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1602

You should also be able to export the settings from one IIS box and import them on the other.